# Are There Any Symbols for Contradictions?

Tags: proof-writing, notation

Perhaps, this question has been answered already but I am not aware of any existing answer. Is there any international icon or symbol for showing **Contradiction** or reaching a contradiction in Mathematical contexts? The same story can be seen for showing that someone reached to the end of the proof of a theorem (i.e. as shown the tombstone symbol ∎, *Halmos*).

Comment: $\Rightarrow\Leftarrow\quad$

Comment: @BillDubuque: Thanks Bill, but I have not seen the symbol through Books. Is it new? :)

Comment: It goes back at least a few decades, if not much older. Alas, I don't recall where I first saw it.

Comment: I’m more familiar with a slight variant of Bill’s symbol, $\rightarrow\leftarrow$, which I’ve used for over 40 years and picked up from other people. I’ve also seen something similar to # but larger and rotated slightly clockwise, though not so often.

Comment: I usually prefer the symbol: $$\text{Contradiction}$$

Comment: I have also seen two small crossed daggers/swords as a symbol for contradiction. The symbol is made up of four line segments, and my professor used to say "no, no, no, no" while drawing it, one no for each line.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: May I ask you to see what I used for contradiction in my last question about $A_n$. It is shown at the end of two proofs. Have you seen this symbol before?

Comment: @Babak: I’ve not seen it before, though I see that it’s mentioned in the Wikipedia article that Cameron cited.

Comment: @utdiscant: That’s almost certainly the #-like symbol that I was trying to describe in my earlier comment.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I think it is enough for Contadiction. :-) Yes, as you noted it is as same Cameron cited. Thanks for the time.

Comment: I've seen a flash used several times, but only on blackboards. I too use it on the blackboard.

Comment: Three different symbols are found in the "List of logic symbols" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols and still others may be used outside logic.

Comment: @Brian Do the authors who write $\rightarrow\leftarrow$ for contradiction, also use $\rightarrow$ vs. $\Rightarrow$ for implication? I have always presumed that $\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$ denotes "two clashing implications". With that view, one uses the same arrows as one uses for implication.

Comment: I've seen # used to indicate a contradiction.

Comment: @Bill: Yes, it’s the same motivation. I use $\Rightarrow$ for implication, if at all, only at the meta level or when accommodating a particular audience; my formal symbol, used on a par with the quantifiers, $\lor$, $\land$, and $\lnot$, is $\to$.

Comment: I personally use the one Bill Dubuque informally, and I've been told that some people abbreviate it to something star-like (draw an X with a horizontal line through the center, it also is supposed to look like two clashing arrows.) I remember another professor trying to convince us that you could use a lightning bolt.

Comment: In writing, you'll probably be better off being clear and using words, not symbols.

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84032/im-confused-does-mean-q-e-d-or-contradiction/84038#84038) is an example of someone using `#` as a contradiction symbol.

Comment: I use ↯, but I only ever use this in my working. If I am writing something up I will always use the word "contradiction" somewhere, and after reading this thread I believe all of you will understand why...

Comment: @user1729 I also ↯ in my own writing and on a blackboard, but I often still add "Contradiction". Usually, it is not a mistake to give students the time it takes to write "contradiction" to ponder the fact that the proof is finished despite the fact that we got something wrong ...

Comment: My algebra professor used `?!`. I found that quite amusing.

Comment: Where I live, it is standard (and literally everyone uses it) is the symbol $\lightning$. We don't use it on latex typing, but everything that goes on blackboard and personal notes etc.

Comment: The "sideways pound sign" can be generated using code shown here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28192/is-there-a-contradiction-symbol-in-some-font-somewhere

Comment: @RobinDawes: thx so much for the link. :-)

Comment: For LaTeX users, some of the mentioned symbols and other suggestions can be found in section 3 of the Comprehensive LaTeX symbols list:https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Different sources use different symbols (if they use symbols at all). I've seen $\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$ most often. For some others, see "Symbolic Representation" [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contradiction).

Comment: I like the \blitza symbol (the first one listed at the link). Apparently, it is commonly used in Germany. I always think it describes the path of a small remote control plane that ends up falling.

Comment: Cute, @Andres. I hadn't seen that and I like its name. +1

Comment: I always thought that was Harry Potter's scar...

Comment: Yes, I really like ↯ as my contradiction symbol.

Comment: The ↯ symbol seems to be very common : in France, my first teacher after high school, used this symbol too (since I use it unconsciously).

Answer (score 37):

I am surprised to see that nobody has mentioned $\bot$. In logic, this is a standard symbol for a formula that is always false, and therefore represents a contradiction exactly.

In almost all logical formalisms, one has a rule of inference that allows one to deduce $p$ from $\bot$ for any $p$ at all, and it is usually possible to prove that $(p\land\lnot p)\to \bot$ and so forth.

Comment: This seems like a pretty standard choice, especially when doing proofs about a logical system. The symbols are `\bot` ($\bot$) and the corresponding `\top` ($\top$) to show tautology.

Comment: This is my favorite answer. What brought me to this post was an impromptu Rorschach test: I came across the symbol $\dashv$ placed at the end of the second-to-last sentence of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/187776) proof by contradiction.  Having (a) never seen that symbol used to mark the end of a proof before, and (b) never even considered the possibility of - let alone known of - any symbol to mark contradiction, despite its position at the end of the proof of the claim in that answer, my brain's first theory about its meaning was that it must be there to mark contradiction.

Comment: My favorite for a completely silly reason: "You bot!" is a common youth insult, meaning "Stupid!". Even sillier given that it's the youth group of my chess club, where a bot would spank them even if set at half ELO...

Comment: The problem about uptack is that it's part of the object language. Whereas when we say we've found a contradiction we are making a judgement in a metalanguage.  IMO a better alternative would be $\vdash \bot$.

Answer (score 24):

Some of my teachers and I use something like (Harry Potter's scar) this $\unicode{x21af}$ (LaTex: `\unicode{x21af}`)

Comment: Also had a professor who always used this.

Comment: This is the only contradiction symbol I've been taught with through both gymnasium (high school) and university. So I would say that it is the most common symbol here in Denmark.
Only place I've seen other symbols have been in english-language books and on the internet.

Comment: `\unicode{x21af}` is giving me an undefined control sequence error.

Comment: @qwertz I believe `\unicode{}` is a XeLaTeX specific command. The package `marvosym` has a `\Lightning` command, that works with PDFLateX and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Also `\blitz` is suggested in the Comprehensive LaTeX symbols list https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive

Answer (score 21):

The symbol I've seen most commonly in mathematical logic statements is also the one which was taught to me in a class called "Discrete Mathematics;" it is something like a sideways number sign or "pound sign" (or "hashtag," as some might call it today).
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpPlS.png]

Comment: How do you generate this symbol?

Comment: @Anthony Try \def\contra{\tikz[baseline, x=0.22em, y=0.22em, line width=0.032em]\draw (0,2.83)--(2.83,0) (0.71,3.54)--(3.54,0.71) (0,0.71)--(2.83,3.54) (0.71,0)--(3.54,2.83);}

Comment: This is in Unicode as U+2A33 ("smash product"), and the `stix` and `boisik` packages have it as `\smashtimes` (according to the CLSL).

Comment: @Anthony `\unicode{10803}` gives $\unicode{10803}$.

Answer (score 11):

I always had used the following notation. At least in my academic environment this one was suggested and used. You can also see these links

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contradiction) (The part "Symbolic representation").
- [TeX](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) (The first page of the section "3 Mathematical symbols").

They both has brought this symbol among symbols that are common for contradiction. About how to type it in TeX with better size, see [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191821/how-to-create-a-larger-symbol).

[image]

Comment: This one is my favourite. I've been looking for it, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

An equivalent to `\blitza` can be found in the package `stmaryrd` in math mode via `\lightning`. Here is another option for the rotated pound sign:

```
\def\contradict
{
\tikz[baseline, x=0.2em, y=0.2em, line width=0.04em]
\draw (0,0) -- ({4*cos(45)},{4*sin(45)})
    (-1,1) -- ({-1 + 4*cos(45)},{1 + 4*sin(45)})
    (-1,3) -- ({-1 + 4*cos(315)},{3 + 4*sin(315)})
    (0,4) -- ({0 + 4*cos(315)},{4 + 4*sin(315)});
}
```

And, although I have never seen that as a contradiction symbol, I have seen $\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$ more often, and use it in my teaching. I generally try to avoid double meaning of symbols so in a class not solely for propositional logic I prefer not to use a perpendicular symbol $\perp$ for contradiction.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `tikz` but I guess your answer is downvoted not due to the content of your `tikz` macro but solely due to the format (because you didn't highlight the codes). I edited as such. Feel free to further improve your post and overwrite my edit. I don't know who downvoted and wish that person hadn't. Please don't feel disheartened.

Answer (score 3):

The bottom and top symbols $\bot,\,\top$ respectively denote contradictions and tautologies in model theory. For example, a proof by contradiction that $\sqrt{2}\notin\mathbb{Q}$ can be rewritten as a proof that $\sqrt{2}\in\mathbb{Q}\to\bot$.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that. +1

Answer (score 3):

The symbol is use came from my professors at Emory University and Auburn University (all Moore Method practitioners) which is octothorp bang, #!

I use it and teach my students to use it.

Answer (score 2):

To indicate contradiction,  I use either of the following three 
 Arial Unicode MS letter-like symbols: Ⓡ or Ⓟ or Ⓒ.  For me,
 Ⓡ indicates *Reduction to Absurdity*; review, revise, redo. (The 3 R's); 
 Ⓟ indicates premise issue;  Ⓒ indicates contradiction.

I got the initial idea from RPC meaning 'Remote Procedure Call'
See *How RPC Works* at https:/technet.microsoft.com,
The purpose is to call in your brain (Remote Procedure) to review, revise
and redo the premises in your logical proofs or electronic designs.
That's the real job.

In philosophy and mathematics, a proof by contradiction, shows the
logical revision of a premise.
Proof by Contradiction
● A proof by contradiction is a proof that works as follows:
● To prove that P is true, assume that P is not true.
● Based on the assumption that P is not true, conclude something impossible.
● Assuming the logic is sound, the only option
is that the assumption that P is not true is incorrect.
● Conclude, therefore, that P is true.

Some Proofs by Contradiction:
MATH
DIY :here are many mathematical proofs by contradiction on the Internet,

RELIGION: Ponder Anselm's Argument for Existence of God
          at http://web.nmsu.edu/~dscoccia/101web/101ONT.pdf

P versus NP Problem:  SEE Wikipedia at
         https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem

LEGAL: Discredit the opponent's argument by showing it is absurd.
SEE: 'Recording and Proof of Contradictions and Omissions, Their Evidential Value and Appreciation of Evidence of Hostile Witnesses' at http://mja.gov.in/Site/Upload/GR/summary%20of%20second%20work%20shop%20criminal%20dated%2010-01-15.pdf.

Comment: Thanks very much for your nice survey. :-)

Answer (score 1):

One that all of my professors back in my college days used was "X" with each stroke looking like an axe.

Comment: I don't know if it's the case, but I've seen people use strange/wrong/non-standard symbols in slides and or lecture notes just due to poor IT skills, lack of fonts in PowerPoint/printer, etc.

Comment: PS: may this be the case reported by user Stefan Octavian?

Comment: @Andrestand Absolutely, I've seen a lot of improvised notations. I spent a long time trying to figure out what diagonal arrows on limits meant, just to find out my professor was feeling artsy that day. This stuff is impossible to look up, too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm 8 years late, but I've seen that this answer is not on the list. In Romania we use a symbol similar to a pair of scissors, that I have learned from both my teachers I've studied with. Unfortunately, I was unable to find such a symbol in MathJax, but I will try reproducing it: $\require{HTML} \style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(30deg) scaleX(-1)}{\flat} \style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(-30deg) scaleX(1)}{\flat}$. Yes, something like that, but with smaller "ears".

Comment: This may be what user drum suggests by axes-like X.

Comment: There are several scissors symbols in the Comprehensive LaTeX symbols list https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive They can be rotated with the command `\rotatebox`.

Answer (score 0):

The symbols are:
$\top$ for truth (example: $100 \in \mathbb{R} \to \top$)
and $\bot$ for false (example: $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q} \to \bot$)

In Latex, `\top` is $\top$ and `\bot` is $\bot$.

Comment: As also mentioned... typical for tautology and always false, respectively, too.

Comment: What kind of arrow is that? "Implies" as in `!a || b` would mean both versions are reducible without needing to look at `a`. "Yields" as in `F: X --> Y` might make sense, but I can't identify `F`. "Maps" would be plausible, but like with "yields" it's describing a subject that isn't there, in this case the map. And if a consistent map or function did send `true --> true` it would just send that to true too, and so on. Sorry I'm slow today.