# Does there exist a kuratowski set which is uncountable

Tags: general-topology

A subset of a topological space is called the Kuratowski set if we can get 14 different sets by applying closures and complementation successively.

I want to find a set which is uncountable and is a Kuratowski set.(I got this idea from Munkres). Is there a set which is uncountable and is a Kuratowski-14 set?

Comment: I can't think of any 14-set on $\mathbb{R}$ that is *not* uncountable. Also, related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186017/what-is-the-smallest-cardinality-of-a-kuratowski-14-set

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_closure-complement_problem).

Comment: From *Characterization of Kuratowski 14-sets* by Eric Langford, Amer. Math. Monthly, p. 362, 1971:

"Suppose that $X$ is a subset of the real line under its usual topology. Then $X$ is a 14-set iff the following: there exists a nonempty open interval $I$ such that $X$ and $Xk$ (the complement of $X$) are both dense in $I$, and both $X$ and $Xk$ contain nonempty, relatively open, nowhere dense subsets of $R$."