# How many natural numbers are needed to generate 14 distinct subsets under complement and multiplicative closure?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, optimization

Let the *multiplicative closure* operator $h$ be defined on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ by setting $hA$ equal to the smallest set containing $A$ that is closed under multiplication.
In L. F. Meyers' solution to Problem E $1941$ on pp. $408$-$9$ of the April $1968$ *American Mathematical Monthly* (https://www.jstor.org/stable/2313449) it is shown that the set $A=\{2,3,14,15,25\}$ generates $14$ distinct subsets under $h$ and the complement operator $c$ on $\mathbb{N}.$
An editorial comment at the end then asks:

*What is the size of the smallest set having the desired property?*

I've never seen this problem mentioned anywhere else, so would guess it is still unsolved.

The "Answer added Nov. 18" section of this answer proves that no Kuratowski 14-set has cardinality $1$ or $2$ in a topological space $X{:}$

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/186428/32209

The proof also works for a *general* closure operator (any operator that is extensive, idempotent, and isotonic) not just a topological one, so the answer to the question above is $3$, $4$, or $5.$*

Given the power of modern computers, maybe someone can find a tripleton of natural numbers that generates the maximum possible number of $14$ distinct subsets under $h$ and $c$?

*$h$ is clearly extensive $(A\subseteq hA$ for all $A)$, idempotent $(hh=h)$, and isotonic $(A_1\subseteq A_2\implies hA_1\subseteq hA_2).$
It is not a topological closure operator though because, for example, $6\in h\{2,3\}\setminus(h\{2\}\cup h\{3\}).$

---------------- update added 15 Feb 2024, edited 28 Feb 2024 ----------------

**1.** It is noteworthy that the set $A$ in the *Monthly* equals $\{p_1,p_2,p_1p_4,p_2p_3,p_3^2\}$ where $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ are the first four primes. We could obviously substitute any four distinct primes and get the same result.

**2.** In light of the proof above, it may have been necessary for Meyers to use all four primes to distinguish $hjhA$ from $jhA.$

**3.** Before taking a close look at this question, I thought the answer would turn out to be $3.$
Now I suspect it is $5.$

**4.** The problem editors were slightly off target when they wrote "Another proof [that $14$ is the maximum number of sets obtainable under $h$ and $c$] is given in J. L. Kelley, *General Topology*, p. $57.$" because it ignores the distinction between the (topological) closure operator in Kelley and the more general one here.

**5.** I just cross-posted this question here with some additional info:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78077889/how-many-natural-numbers-are-needed-to-generate-14-distinct-subsets-under-comple

Comment: You need to only find certain $7$ of those distinct sets, right. The rest will be found already. (potentially minimizes computing power needed)