# Proof by induction that $n^3 + (n + 1)^3 + (n + 2)^3$ is a multiple of $9$. Please mark/grade.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, induction, proof-verification, divisibility

What do you think about my first induction proof? Please mark/grade.

---

### Theorem

The sum of the cubes of three consecutive natural numbers is a multiple of 9.

### Proof

First, introducing a predicate $P$ over $\mathbb{N}$, we rephrase the theorem as follows.
        $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, P(n)
  \quad \text{where} \quad
  P(n) \, := \, n^3 + (n + 1)^3 + (n + 2)^3 \text{ is a multiple of 9}$$
        We prove the theorem by induction on $n$.

#### Basis

Below, we show that we have $P(n)$ for $n = 0$.
            $$0^3 + 1^3 + 2^3 = 0 + 1  +  8 =  9 = 9 \cdot  1$$

#### Inductive step

Below, we show that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $P(n) \Rightarrow P(n + 1)$.

Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$. We assume that $P(k)$ holds.
            In the following, we use this assumption to show that $P(k + 1)$ holds.

By the assumption,
            there is a $i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
            $i \cdot 9 = k^3 + (k + 1)^3 + (k + 2)^3$.
            We use this fact in the following equivalent transformation.
            The transformation turns the sum of cubes in the first line,
            for which we need to show that it is a multiple of 9,
            into a product of 9 and another natural number.

$(k + 1)^3 + (k + 2)^3 + (k + 3)^3 \\
   = (k + 1)^3 + (k + 2)^3 + k^3 + 9k^2 + 27k + 27 \\
   = k^3 + (k + 1)^3 + (k + 2)^3 + 9k^2 + 27k + 27 \quad | \text{ using the induction hypothesis} \\
   = 9i + 9k^2 + 27k + 27 \\
   = 9 \cdot i + 9 \cdot k^2 + 9 \cdot 3k + 9 \cdot 3 \\
   = 9 \cdot (i + k^2 + 3k + 3)$

We see that the above product has precisely two factors: 9 and another natural number.
            Thus the product is a multiple of 9.
            This completes the induction.

Comment: Looks fine to me!

Comment: someone should make something along the lines of markExchange instead of stackExchange. Marking instead of answering sounds fresh and good to me

Comment: Looks good. You could maybe add a Halmos to the end, to be extra if not overly formal, $\square$. Check out http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56606/why-does-drawing-square-mean-the-end-of-a-proof

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides There already is [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), which is essentially "marking code". Perhaps a proofreview StackExchange would be useful.

Answer (score 7):

I do not think that this is a real question but if you were my student i would give you an A.
It is all fine to me.

Answer (score 7):

It's fine, here's a simpler proof without induction:

$n^3\equiv n\ (\text{mod }3)$, because it obviously holds for $n=-1,0,1$.

Therefore $3n^3\equiv3n\ (\text{mod 9})$ and
$$(n-1)^3+n^3+(n+1)^3\equiv3n^3+6n\equiv0\ (\text{mod }9)$$

Comment: i.e. $\ {\rm mod}\ 9\!:\ 3n^3\!+6n\equiv 3(n^3\!-n)\equiv 0\ $ by little Fermat.

Comment: Since $n^3-n = (n-1)n(n+1)$, it is divisible by 3 since it is the product of 3 consecutive integers (actually divisible by 6, but that is not needed here).

Answer (score 4):

Formulation, base case, inductive hypothesis, inductive step, it all looks good. :)

One might also conclude with a clarifying statement about what has been done - that the hypothesis is true for all $n \in \Bbb N$.

Comment: What do you think about the following statement?
"By the basis, the inductive step, and the principle of induction; $P(n)$ is true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$."